# comma operator in c++ doesn't evaluate second expression

Tags: c++, comma-operator

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int f()
{
    cout << "f()" << endl;
    return 3;
}

int v()
{
    cout << "v()" << endl;
    return 4;
}

int main()
{
    int m = f(),v();
    cout << m << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected it to print:

```
f()
v()
3
```

compiling with `g++ -O0 test.cpp -o test.out` and running results:

```
f()
3
```

Why the call to v is omitted? (this can't be do to optimization, because I added the flag `-O0`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the Comma Operator work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
int m = f(),v();
```

This statement executes f() and assign return value to m, then declare function `v()` which return int type. `int v();` also known as [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

To achieve your `comma operator` test, try:

```
int m;
m = f(),v();
cout << m << endl;
```

see [live sample](http://ideone.com/GA3lOy).

Comment: Also note that the comma separator has a lower precedence than the assignment operator.

Comment: @Nawaz see my live sample.

Comment: @Nawaz I tried int m; m= f(), v(); and it produced the expected f()
v()
3

Comment: Also, you can try     int m = (f(),v());

Comment: @billz: I misunderstood the question. +1.

Comment: @billz I wish we could scotch the idea that this is the most vexing parse. If you look at the article you linked to you'll see that the most vexing parse is more complicated `T1 x(T2());` not `T x();`.

Comment: The ambiguity that is present in this declaration has no relation to "most vexing parse" at all.

Answer (score 4):

The following variation of your code demonstrates what this is doing:

http://ideone.com/GBae0p

```
#include <iostream>

int f() { std::cout << "f()" << std::endl; return 1; }

int main() {
   int t = f(), v();
   std::cout << t << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

This compiles without error, even though we don't have a "v()".

The comma operator is splitting this line

```
   int t = f(), v();
```

into

```
   int t = f();
   int v();
```

The second line is a function prototype which declares that there will be a function, `int v()`, which takes no parameters and returns an int.

It doesn't call it, it just pre-declares it - incase the compiler encounters a call it to it before it is actually defined -  because the body is an empty statement (`;`). The compiler assumes we will implement it later or in a different compilation unit.

Because this commonly confuses experience and new programmers alike, because it is introduced by C++ allowing you to put function prototypes inside function bodies, this is called the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).